# How to access DAO from Webservice using JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, spring

Just started using JAX-WS. I created service class and DAO class. My service is running fine but it gives NullPointerExeption b'coz it can't locate to DAO; I am trying to call to DAO from service class :

```
package com.nmmc.works.service.impl;
@WebService(serviceName="MyService")
public class SecurityServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl implements ISecurityService
{   
    private ISecurityDAO securityDAO;

....getter setter methods....

@WebMethod
    public Integer getBidAcceptanceIdForSDPayment(Integer tMastNo)
    {   
        InternalResultsResponse<Object> response = getSecurityDAO().getMyMethod(tenderMastNo);
        if(response != null && response.getResultsList().size() > 0){
            return Integer.parseInt(response.getFirstResult().toString());  
        }else{
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

And sun-jaxws.xml.....

```
<b>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
      <endpoint 
          implementation="com.nmmc.works.service.impl.SecurityDepositServiceImpl"

          name="MyServices" 
          url-pattern="myPath/SecurityServiceImpl"
          />
    </endpoints></b>
```

In web.xml....

```
<b><listener>
      <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebServices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebServices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping></b>
```

Comment: Is getSecurityDAO() successfully instantiating or returning the dao? What does your stacktrace say?

Comment: Where/how are you injecting the DAO implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SecurityServiceImpl doesn't have a DAO in it when you run it. You'll have to ensure that a DAO is properly created and injected into/obtained by it.

Comment: Actually when remove Annotation from Service it works fine when place Annotations as given above it reaches at Service but at it can't instantiate dao.my works-service-application-context.xml <bean id="securityServiceImpl" class="com.nmmc.works.service.impl.SecurityServiceImpl">
  <property name="securityDAO" ref="securityDAOTarget"></property>  
 </bean>  and works-dao-application-context.xml <bean id="securityDAOTarget" class="com.nmmc.works.dao.impl.SecurityDAOImpl">
  <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="cessHibernateTemplate"/>
 </bean>

Comment: @mezmo It can't instantiate DAO hence it returns null...I configured service in works-service-application-context.xml <bean id="securityServiceImpl" class="com.nmmc.works.service.impl.SecurityServiceImpl">
  <property name="securityDAO" ref="securityDAOTarget"></property>  
 </bean> and DAO in works-dao-application-context.xml  <bean id="securityDAOTarget" class="com.nmmc.works.dao.impl.SecurityDAOImpl">
  <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="cessHibernateTemplate"/>
 </bean>

Comment: @Balasaheb: What uses your security service, and where does it get the service from?

Comment: I configured all beans in .xml file. I have not configured these xml files in webservice configuration file hence my service can't locate to that file, But when I create instance of DAO in Service class it entered in DAO but there also has call to Hibernate. So is there any way to include bean definition files in web-service config file?

Comment: @Balasheb: I don't know what your "web-service config file" is, but unless you're using AspectJ weaving, you can't just "new" a service or DAO and expect it to work without setting all of its dependencies appropriately.